# MYSQL syntax, merge two queries

Tags: mysql

I want a table identifier to be on count(*) so that I can combine these two queries 
Query 1

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM
    Table1 OP
WHERE
    OP.TARGET_ID=?
```

Query2

```
SELECT
    T.TARGET_NAME, T.TARGET_PUBLIC_NAME
FROM
    KB_TARGETS T
WHERE
    T.TARGET_ID = ?;
```

into

```
SELECT
    T.TARGET_NAME, T.TARGET_PUBLIC_NAME, OP.COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM
    Table2 T,Table1 OP
WHERE
    T.TARGET_ID = ?;
```

Please help with the syntax. I belive I need a table identifier on count but don't know how to do that

Thanks

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: no, but I feel like I should now

Comment: three columns with 1 row in each

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
    T.TARGET_NAME, T.TARGET_PUBLIC_NAME, OP.COUNT(*) AS COUNT
FROM
    Table2 T join Table1 OP on T.TARGET_ID=P.TARGET_ID
WHERE
    T.TARGET_ID = ?;
group by T.TARGET_NAME, T.TARGET_PUBLIC_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

As I interpret it, the simplest way to use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT T.TARGET_NAME, T.TARGET_PUBLIC_NAME,
       (SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT
        FROM Table1 OP
        WHERE OP.TARGET_ID = T.TARGET_ID
       ) as cnt
FROM KB_TARGETS T
WHERE T.TARGET_ID = ?;
```

You have to be very careful with using a `JOIN`.  The `COUNT()` will be incorrect if `TARGET_ID` is on multiple rows of `KB_TARGETS`.  The correlated subquery is a much safer solution.